# PHP Echo function

Tags: php

I'm using a comment script on this page im building. I want for eacht page the comments to say: "Reaction on (each page different name)".

So I found the line what says this but it wont grab on to the echo function.
This is the line:

```
<H3>{$COM_LANG['header']}</H3>
```

The header is the part of "Reaction on" and I want to echo behind the company name thats different for each page.

I tried:

```
<H3>{$COM_LANG['header']} $companyname; </H3>
```

But it wont work...

EDIT: Sorry if i'm not clear, maby its because i'm dutch and don't know hoe to explaine something in english.

Here a piece of code where this is all about:

```
<div id="usernotes">
 <div class="head">
 <H3>{$COM_LANG['header']} </H3>
 <br>
 </div>
EOF;

 if ($comments_count) {
  for($i=0; $i<$comments_count; $i++) {
   if ($dont_show_email[$i] != '1' && $email != '') { $author[$i] = "<a href=\"mailto:{$email[$i]}\">{$author[$i]}</a>"; }
   $text[$i] = str_replace(chr(13), '<br />', $text[$i]);

   print<<<EOF
 <div class="note">
  <strong>{$author[$i]}</strong><br />
  <small>{$time[$i]}</small>
  <div class="text">
  {$text[$i]}
  </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"So I found"* - where did you found that? That part of your code that you posted, looks very good! Please post all code, thanks in advance!

Comment: The header part is linked to a language file and there it says "Reaction on". And thats on everypage with the comment script, but I also want to add the name of the company where they can write a reaction on. So it would look like "Reaction on company name".

Comment: Your best bet would be doing a var_dump() of $GLOBALS on a page that you know the company name, finding it in the page and seeing how it's accessible to PHP. Then add it in between the curly braces, since whatever script you're using may only evaluate what's in between.

Comment: This looks like a templating engine. It doesn't even have `echo` statements. :-?

Comment: `echo` **is not a function**. It is a **language construct**, just like `if`, `while` and `die` (to name a few).

Answer (score 0):

if `<H3>{$COM_LANG['header']}</H3>` does output what it's supposed to you can try either `<H3>{$COM_LANG['header'] . $companyname}</H3>` or `<H3>{$COM_LANG['header']} . {$companyname}</H3>`

Anyway you'd make things easier to everybody showing the PHP code that transforms the above declaration into HTML: is there a template engine, maybe?

Comment: I really don't know if there is... I'm not good with php I can raed some but not write it. I'm sorry people for being un specified. 

And there are to many files to show here all codes and everything. Thats why I posted the line where I think the "Reaction to" text comes from...

Comment: Oh, well. The thing seems to be the Comments script at Scriptsmill.com (thank you, Google). The reason $companyname doesn't work is that the HTML above is used within a function, so any globally declared variable is out of scope unless specifically included (as $COM_LANG indeed is). The working syntax should thus be {$GLOBALS['companyname']}.

Answer (score 0):

The application might be using a templating language. This on looks like [Latte](http://doc.nette.org/en/templating). So you might want this:

```
<H3>{$COM_LANG['header']} {$companyname} </H3>
```

Comment: No that does not work, tried that already. I figured it out by adding $COM_LANG['companyname'] to the language file and also in the comments.php and now it works propperly. But thanks, and also thanks 2 everyone else who tried :D